# one variable with multi assignments in java

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment

```
double balance = loanAmount,principal,interest;
```

Can someone explain about this variable and multi assignments? How it is possible that "balance" can have 3 assignments (loanAmount, principal, and interest)?

Comment: Sure it's valid. It's a declaration of 3 variables, one of which is initialized.

Comment: @Pshemo It will compile, but only because comma has a little-used syntactic meaning of evaluating both expressions and returning the last one.  It is sometimes used in for loops, such as `for (i = 1, j = 2; i < max; i++, j++).`  In this situation, though, it makes no sense.

Comment: @Zag - I think you're confusing Java and C.  There is no 'comma operator' in Java.  The example you give is specific to `for`, not general expression syntax. And it's a list of statement expressions, not expressions -- i.e., the list has no value.

Comment: @Zag I stand corrected, it can compile if we assume that `loanAmount` is variable that was already declared and is guaranteed to be initialized. Removed my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement follows the form

```
<type> <identifier> [ '=' <expression> ] [',' <identifier> [ '=' <expression> ] ...]
```

So you're doing this:

- Declare a variable of type `double` with the name `balance` and assign the value of `loanAmount` to it;
- Declare a variable of type `double` with the name `principal`;
- Declare a variable of type `double` with the name `interest`.

See [JLS § 14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) for more details.

I wouldn't advise this kind of declaration, but it *is* valid.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration is valid iff there is a prior declaration of loanAmount.

Perhaps:

```
 void someFunction(double loanAmount) {
     double balance = loanAmount,principal,interest;
       :
 }
```

Or maybe

```
 double loanAmount = 1234.56;
 double balance = loanAmount,principal,interest;
```

The declaration is equivalent to

```
 double balance = loanAmount;
 double principal;
 double interest;
```

3 variables are declared; 1 of them is initialized.

Comment: double loanAmount = 1234.56;
 double balance = loanAmount,principal,interest;                                                                                can you please explain this a bit further? Thanks

Comment: I'm at a loss to say anything more than is already in my answer, especially the last paragraph which explains what your code means in terms of simpler declarations.

Comment: @canpip it is similar to case like `int x=1, y, z;` which *declares* 3 variables: `x`, `y` and `z`, BUT only `x` is initialized with value `1`. Rest of variables (the `y` and `z`) will not be initialized (at least not explicitly since class or instance *fields* will get default values if they are not initialized explicitly). IF we have another variable like `int n = 1;` we can rewrite that example like `int x = n, y, z;` in which case `x` will also be initialized with `1` (since that is value held by `n`) and `y` and `z` will not be initialized - at least not explicitly.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you @ArfurNarf

Answer (score 1):

you did not include the block of code which you declared a variable loanAmount, principal, and interest.

Simple Exlanation is if calculating balance is what you want to achieve, you can try this code:

```
    double loanAmount = 1000;
    double principal = 1;
    double interest = 5;
    double balance = (loanAmaount * interest) * principal;
```

something like that.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since the valid declaration `double balance = loanAmount,principal,interest;` does not appear in your answer.  (Also, your answer does not compile, because of a typo)

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned the values of `principal` and `interest` to `balance` - only `loanAmount`.

Instead you have created other variables `principal` and `interest` of type double. To perform multiple assignments, simply do:

```
double loanAmount, principal, interest;
double balance = loanAmount = principal = interest;
```

Ensure that `loanAmount`, `principal` and `interest` are declared and initialized **earlier** before assignment.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since the valid declaration `double balance = loanAmount,principal,interest;` does not appear in your answer.

Comment: And in what financial system does setting principal, loanAmount, and balance to the interest make any sense?  If interest is a rate (like 0.05, or 5%) then the code as written is dimensionally unsound (balance can't be a rate).  If interest is an amount (like 5 units of currency) then it's just semantic nonsense; ok, principal and interest could be the same, if it's a 100% interest rate, but in that case the balance is surely principal + interest.

Comment: @ArfurNarf My answer was only for demonstrative purposes so that the OP understands multiple declarations and assignments, not to teach any financial concepts.